# Using sed to read data from one file and insert after the second line of text in another file

Tags: sed

Can't find this anywhere in my teacher's lectures and no one seems to have answered it online.
How do I use sed to take lines from one file and place them in between the lines of another file?

I know it's probably a simple question but I swear I can't find how to do it.

I attempted

`sed '2r myfile.txt' mydata.txt > mydata.txt`

but it deletes the mydata.txt lines entirely

Comment: please update the question with sample data from both files, and the expected output

Comment: if you've verified `sed '2r myfile.txt' mydata.txt` generates the correct results, you have a couple options ... `sed '2r myfile.txt' mydata.txt > tmpfile; mv tmpfile mydata.txt` or if using `GNU sed` then `sed -i '2r myfile.txt' mydata.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If your `mydata.tx` is a typo and you are using `mydata.txt`, you cannot redirect to the input file, it will truncate it to empty before you even get started. Use `sed -i '2r myfile.txt' mydata.txt` or else write it to a file with another filename and rename it if necessary. (The `-i` will cause `sed` to update the input file with the output, basically automatically doing what I suggest.)